# Double Quotes with opencsv (java)

Tags: java, csv, opencsv

I am using opencsv to read a file in Java.
This is my config for the reader

```
try (Reader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(pathToFile)) {
    CSVParser parser = new CSVParserBuilder().withSeparator(";").build();
    try (CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReaderBuilder(reader).withSkipLines(1)
        .withCSVParser(parser).build()) {
        List<String[]> csvFileData = csvReader.readAll();
        ....
    }}
```

My CSV file has following line:

> 123;00234;123;Max "Mustermann";something

The Result after parsing is:

> Max "Mustermann

The double Quote at the end disappears.

Is there any possibility to config the CsvParser to keep the quotes at the end of the field, I have tried withIgnoreQuotations(true), but that has no effect?

Comment: If this really is what your CSV parser is doing, then it's failing to do CSV correctly at a fundamental level. May I suggest switching to a *capable* CSV parser?

Comment: mhm I think the CSV format isn't correctly, I guess the format should be "text "" other text""".  Then the result is fine. But I need a solution for this "not correctly" CSV format.

Comment: Is the CSV in your control? Can you just try to have `123;00234;123;"Max ""Mustermann""";something` in your CSV and see if it works?

Comment: The CSV spec says it's allowed to quote fields. And if you do, any quotes in the text should be escaped. It doesn't say it's okay to remove a quote at the end of a text if there's no quote at the start.

Comment: Yeah, 2-quotes should be used inside the data to escape quotes and that should result in one quote when extracted as value, and the whole field value should be enclosed in quotes.

Comment: The problem is, no I have the CSV not under my control :-) I could manipulate it, but if possible I would like avoid this.

Comment: @deadpoint The source CSV is not the problem. It's perfectly valid. The problem is your parser has a bug.

Comment: Use Apache Commons CSV - https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/download_csv.cgi - I used 1.10.0 - it works on your CSV sample record without any change. I just tried with that string as input:
`CSVRecord [comment='null', recordNumber=1, values=[123, 00234, 123, Max "Mustermann", something]]` - parses and returns proper record

Answer (score 1):

Using Apache Commons CSV parser - https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/download_csv.cgi - Version 1.10.0.

```
String str = "123;00234;123;Max \"Mustermann\";something";
try (CSVParser parser = CSVParser.parse(str, CSVFormat.DEFAULT.builder().setDelimiter(';').build())) {
    parser.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Parses and returns it properly:

```
CSVRecord [comment='null', recordNumber=1, values=[123, 00234, 123, Max "Mustermann", something]]
```